# Debugging INNER JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using the query below that joins the two tables below that, I am returning every record in the database. Can someone explain why and show me my error?

```
 SELECT orderdetails.orderNumber,
    orderdetails.productCode,
    orderdetails.quantityOrdered,
    orderdetails.priceEach,
    orders.orderDate
  FROM orderdetails INNER JOIN orders
    ON orderdetails.orderNumber = orders.orderNumber;
```

In the "orders" table the primary key is "orderNumber". In the orderdetails table the primary keys are orderNumber and productCode. I feel that the answer lies in understanding this but I don't quite get it.

Comment: That makes sense.  You have no `where` clause.  What do you want the query to return?

Comment: Haha that question edit helped a lot! Now your question makes sense. Thank you Gordon.

Comment: Here is the task  Using an inner join, generate and run a query that will return the order number, product code, quantity ordered, price each, and order date for all orders.

Comment: @BryanSchlund That is exactly what you are doing. What is your question?

Comment: That's what you have. Your query is fine.

Comment: The query you have will return all the data, if you need details for a specific order, then have a where condition

Comment: It just seems strange that is returning all 2996 records in my database. Ok, fair enough. The next portion asks me to specify further so I add this       WHERE orderNumber = 10349; and when I do I get the same return

Comment: @BryanSchlund That is the intention of the inner join. An inner join selects and combines all rows from two tables for which the ON condition is true. You most likely have many orders (and I assume you have order details for most/all of them), and thus you also expect many results.

Comment: It just seems strange that is returning all 2996 records in my database. Ok, fair enough. Thank you, my issue is resolved. Studying remotely can remove some of the context of these assignments. I suppose my professor just wanted to show us what happens when we dont specify with a WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

both the table has matched orderNumber & same no. of records & as there is no where clause, so it fetched all data.